# Método sendo chamado duas vezes ao carregar página

Tags: jsf, hibernate, primefaces

Tenho um sistema `JSF+PrimeFaces` e uma página onde tenho um dataTable, esse dataTable é preenchido da seguinte forma:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tarefaBean.listar()}" id="tarefaTable"
                var="tarefa" style="margin-top: 20px"
                emptyMessage="Nenhuma Tarefa Encontrada. " rows="10"
                paginator="true">
```

O método `tarefaBean` retorna uma lista de `Tarefa`, lista que preenche a `dataTable`.

O problema é que a cada `F5` ou cada renderização da página esse método é chamado duas vezes, ou seja, duas consultas são realizadas no banco de dados.

Exemplo do resultado que sai no console:

```
Metodo Listarnull
Hibernate: select usuario0_.codigo as codigo1_1_0_, usuario0_.cargo as cargo2_1_0_, usuario0_.login as login3_1_0_, usuario0_.nome as nome4_1_0_, usuario0_.senha as senha5_1_0_ from tbl_usuario usuario0_ where usuario0_.codigo=?

Metodo Listarnull
Hibernate: select usuario0_.codigo as codigo1_1_0_, usuario0_.cargo as cargo2_1_0_, usuario0_.login as login3_1_0_, usuario0_.nome as nome4_1_0_, usuario0_.senha as senha5_1_0_ from tbl_usuario usuario0_ where usuario0_.codigo=?
```

Método listar:

```
public List<Tarefa> listar() {
        List<Tarefa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        System.err.println("Metodo Listar" +tarefa);
        try {
            TarefaDAO tarefaDAO = new TarefaDAO();
            lista = tarefaDAO.listarPorUsuario(usuarioBean.getUsuarioLogado());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao listar tarefas: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

**OBS:** O meu Bean é `@ViewScoped`

Comment: Techies, porque não faz um lazyload atrelando essa lista a uma propriedade do Bean? É comum alguns componentes chamarem as MethodExpressions mais de uma vez, dê uma olhada nessa resposta do BalusC no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: vou pesquisar sobre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Isso é um comportamento padrão do JSF e da sua EL (Expression Language). A verdade é que um método de uma EL pode ser invocado inúmeras vezes dependendo do componente e ciclo de vida, por esse motivo você deve evitar lógicas caras dentro dos métodos getters - quando falo de lógica cara me refiro a consultas ao banco de dados, web services etc!

Uma solução para seu problema é tirar o código do getter e movê-lo para um método de callback anotado com `@PostConstruct`, algo como:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // seu código vai aqui
}
```

Este método será invocado após a criação do managed bean e após a injeção de dependências (DI) do seu framework.

Para entender melhor como a EL trabalha e outras alternativas eu recomendo o artigo [JSF: Não coloque lógica cara em métodos getters](http://blog.triadworks.com.br/jsf-nao-coloque-processamento-caro-em-metodos-getters).

Um abraço,